# How do I predict the probability of churning out in the next month for e-commerce customers?

Tags: regression, time-series, classification, churn

**Data:**

- **Customer details** : Name, registration device, state province, referrer, registration datetime, activation datetime
- **Product details**
- **Transaction details**

**Prediction:**

I need to predict what is the probability that a customer is going to churn out on the first day of next month.

**Problem facing:**

I have created a classification model to predict whether a customer is going to churn out or not (It does not matter when he is going to churn out).  I have created a regression model also to predict after how many days from the registration is the customer going to churn out(With an RMSE of 170 which is very high).

So not only my regression RMSE is very high, but I don't know how to go about predicting the probability of churning out for a particular date, and in this case it is the first of the next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Cox Regression applied in churn prediction: http://daynebatten.com/2015/02/customer-churn-cox-regression/